# Problem in compiling a CV in Texmaker from a template in overleaf

Tags: xetex, margins, cv

I am trying to use a template taken from overleaf for my cv.
Here's the one I am trying to modify:
[template](https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/my-resume/qxsxdtmknkfr)

the problem is that I'd like to have it all in my computer and not overleaf.
I created a folder, put all the files in it, but when I compile (LulaTex), I get this:

[image]

As you can see, everything is out of the page (if I compile with lulatek)
if I compile with pdfLateX I get the error message:

```
! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec) LuaTeX.
```

I have no clue on what to do.

Comment: Joke: I would remove the `\skill{LaTeX}{4}` part...

Comment: Overleaf lets you download the whole project as a zip file. Did you do that?

Comment: nope, I couldn't find the button, so I did copy and paste of the all project

Comment: now i downloaded the zip files, run trough lulatex and still have the same output

Comment: I suggest that you modify your title of the question, e. g. using the actual error message. Currently, the title is misleading in my opinion.

Comment: The file runs fine for me with LuaLaTeX. Maybe you have an older version of LaTeX? With versions starting from 2019 it works ok (you can check this in Overleaf by setting 'TeX Live version' in the menu, with 2017 or 2018 you get the error and incorrect output that you describe, with 2019 or 2020 you get the correct output). Try updating your local installation.

Comment: finally it works with LuLaTeX, I deleted and re-installed LaTex and it wokks as I wished.

Answer (score 2):

- I recommend using the "normal" export function that Overleaf conveniently provides.
- You also see the used compiler etc. In my case, the compiler is **NOT lualatex**.

[image]
[image]

Comment: in my case, overleaf, for that template, the coompiller is set too xlatek

Comment: @Noob_Latex I assume you mean "XeLaTeX" and not "xlatex". Make sure that your "TeXLive version "is the same on your computer and in Overleaf to avoid version problems.

Comment: @Noob_Latex You can test to use the same compiler on Overleaf and your local machine.

Comment: when I use XeLateX and Lulatex in overleaf everything is ok. When I use XelaTex in Tekmaker it just prints out the layout without anything in it. With LuLatex in Tekmaker, it displays as I shown in the first picture, but I get this 2 error messages:   ! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \Ifthispageodd{\@highlightbar \hspace {\dimexpr \marginleft +\marginright }\@m \makebody

Comment: if I set pdfLaTeX as a compiler in overleaf, it doesn't compile